# Using four-vectors to solve a relativity question

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, kinematics

I am having trouble solving a physics problem. I have tried for several hours, but I cannot come up with what I am doing wrong. It might just be a silly mistake. This is a problem from Morin's Special Relativity book. I am trying to get better at these types of questions.

**Problem:**

Train A with proper length $L$ moves eastward at speed $v$, while train B 
with proper length $2L$ moves westward also at speed $v$. How much time 
does it take for the trains to pass each other (defined as the time 
between the fronts coinciding and the backs coinciding) in the A and B's frame?

**My attempt:**

I know that in the ground frame, the time for A to pass B is $3L/2\gamma v$, so this should be the same in both A and B's frame. But, when I'm calculating the time in A's frame of reference, I'm getting a different answer. Here is my work:

Let A be the event that the back of the A train and let B be the back of the B train. Also, define $x = 0$ to be the back of the A train when the front of trains A and B are touching. In the ground frame, we have

$$A = \begin{bmatrix} 
ct \\ vt\\0\\0
\end{bmatrix}, \text{and }  B = \begin{bmatrix} 
ct \\ 3L - vt\\0\\0
\end{bmatrix}$$

Transforming to A's frame yields (here, $\beta = v/c$)

$$ \begin{bmatrix}
\gamma & -\beta\gamma & 0 & 0 \\
-\beta\gamma & \gamma & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}\cdot A = \begin{bmatrix}
\gamma ct - \beta \gamma vt \\
0\\
0\\
0
\end{bmatrix}$$

Then, transforming B to A's frame yields

$$\begin{bmatrix}
\gamma & -\beta\gamma & 0 & 0 \\
-\beta\gamma & \gamma & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix} \cdot B = \begin{bmatrix}
\gamma ct - \beta\gamma(3L - vt) \\
-\beta\gamma ct + \gamma(3L - vt) \\
0\\
0
\end{bmatrix}.$$

Equating A' and B' yields $t = 3L/2v$, which is missing a factor of $1/\gamma$.

Does anyone know where I went wrong?

Comment: According to time dilation, the time in the trains' frames should agree to be $\frac{3L}{2v \gamma^2}$. Since the events happen at different ends of the trains, there is loss of simultaneity as well. I managed to solve this problem by applying the fundamental effects one by one.

Comment: Welcome *New contributor* Joseph Man!  I've identified some conceptual errors in your thinking.  (1) How did you conclude that the elapsed time according to a clock on either train should equal the elapsed time according to a station clock?  (2) Why are the train lengths not contracted in the station frame?  (3) You seem to be (improperly) calculating $t$ rather than $t'$ or $t''$ ( the elapsed time in the A or B frame)

Answer (score 0):

You forgot that the lengths of trains A and B are Lorentz contracted when observed in the ground frame. 
To account for this Lorentz contraction, we should divide the 3L in your expression for $B$ by a factor $\gamma$:
$$  B = \begin{bmatrix} 
ct \\ \frac{3L}{\gamma} - vt\\0\\0
\end{bmatrix}.$$

Using this $B$ results in the desired answer.